# org.json unreported exception while creating a JSONObject

Tags: java, json

Can anyone help me understand what is going wrong?

```
unreported exception org.json.JSONException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    jsonObj = new JSONObject("{\"count\":3939,\"has_more\":true,\"map_location\":{\"lat\":0.60996950000000183,\"lon\":-27.568517000000003,\"panoramio_zoom\":16},\"photos\":[{\"height\":375,}]}"); //creates the JSON object from the jsonString, for parsing
              ^
```

1 error

I'm using org.json, and I think I have everything set up correctly. I'm trying to create a JSONObject using the constructor in org.json that takes a source string, and I keep getting this exception. I'm not sure what is wrong with the string that I am sending in. Thanks

Comment: You need to read up on what checked exceptions are in Java - it will clear up this situation for you. Note that this is a *compile* error, which means it has nothing to do with the string you're passing in.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Catch your Exception by creating try and catch:

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("{\"count\":3939,\"has_more\":true,\"map_location\":{\"lat\":0.60996950000000183,\"lon\":-27.568517000000003,\"panoramio_zoom\":16},\"photos\":[{\"height\":375,}]}");          
    System.out.println(jsonObj);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    //some exception handler code.
}
```

Or either throws your exception to caller method:

```
public String yourMethod(String jsonString) throws JSONException
```

Answer (score 2):

[constructor declares to throw](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29) `org.json.JSONException` so you must handle it (catch & handle or rethrow to let caller handle it)